# What isPCI domain,Iknow bus,slot,function,bt what exactly a pci Domain.R there any fixed number of pci domains standard means predefined domain values

Tags: linux, pci, pci-e

I like to know when I see the pci address like `00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (re`

how to make sense  of this address what is first 00 in `00:1c.6` and what is 1c in `00:1c.6` and what is 6 in `00:1c.6`

Where is domain and is 6 is a bus? or slot? or function? I know there can be = number of bits than 1 byte to represent 15 pci devices connected to pci bus. But how many pci devices can I connect to single bus is there any limit? or its unlimited then it makes no sense. But I can relate to bus number, bus address, slot number but what the heck is pci domain. I couldnt find any source which explains specifically this, they talk about addresses and configuration space but skip the domain altogether.

How many pci domains are there are they predefined? And how to just read pci address string like `00:1c.6` in lspci output

Comment: In 00:1c.6, 00 is the bus, 1c is the device, and 6 is the function.

Comment: In PCIe, there is normally only one device per bus (except for bus 0, which can have up to 31).

Comment: When you say "PCI domain" do you mean PCI segment? PCI segment is 0 in most systems, so it often isn't shown. Where did you read the term "PCI domain"?

Comment: @prl in kernel there is missing parameter for domain for me for various functions in linux/pci.h file. That's why this question.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49090341, which explains PCIe segments / domains in detail.